# How can I remove all the features from video.js

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to use http://www.videojs.com , 
I have embedded the player successfully ,  how can I remove all the controls and feature and use only the api to manipulate the video ?
From the documentation I use the following but is not working.

```
data-setup='{ "children": { "controlBar": false, "TextTrackDisplay": false, "BigPlayButton": false, "LoadingSpinner": false, "TextTrackDisplay": }}'>
```

Comment: Have you actually looked at the documentation? https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md

Comment: Here is one option to hide, not remove, but maybe it help you: [http://blog.videojs.com/post/57828375480/hiding-and-showing-video-player-controls](http://blog.videojs.com/post/57828375480/hiding-and-showing-video-player-controls)